# Multi user access in admin panel is different folders for admin and other users

Tags: php, mysql, directory

I have an admin panel and I have two roles (admin and publisher). I want to give publisher access to some pages, like only update and add view of news and admin have all things. Do I have to make a separate folder for admin and for publisher? Please tell me about the structure of admin and publisher. I have now admin panel folder and in admin folder I have different pages like for add news update news and add publishers. I want that the publisher only has access to two pages add news and update news. Do I have to make different folders?

Comment: You can add conditions as per user login. First of all you need to create database and add role wise permission. e.g create table call permission. and give relation ship with user role and add all permissions

Comment: no need to create any other folder you can create a session publisher and save publisher id in it then if session publisher id == login publisher id then you can show these pages]

Comment: I am thinking as actually its links with different pages in admin. if the it login with publisher each index page have all links which admin already have . so why it not show to publisher then?

Comment: sum people using enum varibale for admin and publisher what is this enum can i use for this?